# Real Time trend direction

Tags: wonderware

Since Real Time trend plots right to left, is there a way to change the direction so it will plot left to right and when the pen gets to about 75% of the charts width, the chart shifts to the left 50% of the charts width and continues plotting?

Answer (score 0):

The trend is always plotting left to right. But it looks different since you start with an empty plot. This would look different if you had connected it to Historian where you would start with a full plot.

The trend control has a property called "RefreshTimes" which continuously updates the end time to current time. If you set this property to 0, your trend will have static start and end times. The trend line(s) should still update, making it plot from left to right.

You can then control the start and end times through scripting.